# bash scripting unexpected output with file containing string like "[1]"

Tags: bash, shell

I am using following string to parse every line of file to create new string

```
#!/bin/bash

HierTreeFile=$1

while read line; do
  strFound=`echo $line | grep "Var:"`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
      signalName=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
          suffix=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
      i=3
#          echo "before " $i $suffix
      while [ $suffix != "l:-1" ];do
#          echo "${suffix:0:1}"
          i=$((i+1))
#          echo "before " $i $suffix
          signalName=$signalName$suffix
          suffix=`echo $line | awk -v i="$i" '{print $i}'`
#          echo "after " $i $suffix
      done
      echo $signalName
  fi
done < $HierTreeFile
```

File passed to above script is as follows :

```
Var: Vidhu** [7] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [6] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [5] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [4] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [3] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [2] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [1] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** {1} l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [0] l:-1
```

I am getting following output :

```
Vidhu**[7]
Vidhu**[6]
Vidhu**[5]
Vidhu**[4]
Vidhu**[3]
Vidhu**[2]
Vidhu**1
Vidhu**{1}
Vidhu**[0]
```

why am i getting this unexpected output (**Vidhu**1** )with this script ?

Comment: you might not have space around "Var: Vidhu** [1] l:-1"

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but you could easily improve your implementation by either using a single `awk` script or using the builtin `shift` to browse through the parameters

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce your error with your posted data and script, so I'm voting to close the question. You should check SMA's suggestion.

Comment: @SMA there is space between Vidhu** and [ in every line.

Comment: @Aaron can you give me link where this script is not reproducible, if possible.

Comment: @Spartacus I don't know how, it looks like ideone.com doesn't want me to execute script ([snippet](https://ideone.com/Oif1D1)).

Comment: @Aaron my current shell is : echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
Is this affect the output ?
I tried https://ideone.com/Qip4ia. and it gives correct output but on my shell i am getting 1.

Comment: @Spartacus it shouldn't matter as your script uses a shebang

Comment: @Spartacus wait, is that echo inside your script? If so, your environment might link /bin/bash to /bin/csh. I don't know the first thing about csh, but as suggested earlier you could make that whole script into an awk script that should be portable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `csh`; `$SHELL` is the name of your login shell, not the shell currently running. What is the output that you *want*, the bracketed number after `Vidhu**`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (GNU & BSD?) `sed` implementation that should work :

```
sed -nE 's/^Var: (.*) .*/<\1>/;s/ //gp' inputFile
```

This will only print on lines that start with `Var:`, replacing them by every field but the first and last concatenated without space.

It relies on Extended Regular Expressions, which can be activated on BSD and newer GNU `sed`s with the `-E` flag, and on older GNU `sed` with the `-r` flag.

```
$ echo "Var: Vidhu** [7] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [6] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [5] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [1] l:-1
Var: Vidhu** {1} l:-1
Var: Vidhu** [0] l:-1" | sed -nr 's/^Var: (.*) .*/\1/;s/ //gp'
Vidhu**[7]
Vidhu**[6]
Vidhu**[5]
Vidhu**[1]
Vidhu**{1}
Vidhu**[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making multiple calls to external programs, just use `bash`'s regular expression capabilities.

```
regex='Var: [^ ]* ([^ ]+) l:-1'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        signalName=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        echo "$signalName"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
[7]
[6]
[5]
[4]
[3]
[2]
[1]
{1}
[0]
```

Comment: If I read OP's code correctly, this doesn't handle all its cases : it looks like the input could contain more than 4 fields, and that all but the first and last should be concatenated (without their delimiter).

Comment: @Aaron, yes, you are right there are multiple fields

Comment: So change the regex to suit :- regex='Var:[^\]]*([^ ]+)'